# There is a jQuery selector for childs between N and M position?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Lets say i have a list of elements and i want to select the childs greater than 2 :eq(2) and smaller than 6 :eq(6). I know how to select grater than with :gt() but i dont know how to select between N and M position. There is a selector for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mix them both: `$('...:gt(2):lt(4)')`.

It is `:lt(4)` because `:lt()` "Selects all elements at an index less than index **within the matched set**". So 6-2 should be used.

Thanks to Joachim Isaksson for pointing it out :)

Comment: Actually, that'd be `:gt(2):lt(3)` since they're chained, ie the `lt` applies only on the elements remaining after the `gt`.

Answer (score 5):

you can always use `.slice()` <sup>[DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)</sup>

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/udonew/1/edit)**

```
$('ul li').slice(2,5)
```

Comment: Your answer is ok too but its not jQuery. Thats why i choose Sidharth Mudgal answer as the correct one. Thanks anyway, your response can be useful to many others.

Comment: @JonathanCalb FYI jQuery === Javascript (ECMAScript)

Comment: I know. jQuery is a framework for Javascript. Its Javascript yes. But i want an answer to jQuery Framework. If is that what you mean. Thanks anyway, really. The problem can be solved with your code too.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do this:

```
$('ul li').filter(function(i,elm){ 
    return (i>=2 && i<6);}
).addClass('red');
```